# Assembler code not compileable in online compiler

Tags: assembly

I was trying to solve a "digital puzzle" and got a bit of assembly code. Sadly I have no clue about it, so i tried to past it into an online compiler, but its throwing errors at every line:

```
.file   "0x0c.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Pa"
.LC1:
    .string "h15"
.LC2:
    .string "wb0"
.LC3:
    .string "u77"
.LC4:
    .string "rd: "
.LC5:
    .string "wo"
.LC6:
    .string "ss"
.LC7:
    .string "h0"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $1104, %rsp
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -1104(%rbp)
    leaq    .LC1(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -1096(%rbp)
    leaq    .LC2(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -1088(%rbp)
    leaq    .LC3(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -1080(%rbp)
    leaq    .LC4(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -1072(%rbp)
    leaq    .LC5(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -1064(%rbp)
    movq    -1104(%rbp), %rdx
    leaq    -1040(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    strcat@PLT
    leaq    .LC6(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -1056(%rbp)
    movq    -1056(%rbp), %rdx
    leaq    -1040(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    strcat@PLT
    movq    -1064(%rbp), %rdx
    leaq    -1040(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    strcat@PLT
    movq    -1072(%rbp), %rdx
    leaq    -1040(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    strcat@PLT
    leaq    .LC7(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -1048(%rbp)
    movq    -1048(%rbp), %rdx
    leaq    -1040(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    strcpy@PLT
    movq    -1088(%rbp), %rdx
    leaq    -1040(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    strcat@PLT
    movq    -1080(%rbp), %rdx
    leaq    -1040(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    strcat@PLT
    movq    -1096(%rbp), %rdx
    leaq    -1040(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    strcat@PLT
    movl    $0, %eax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rcx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rcx
    je  .L3
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT
.L3:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 7.3.1 20180312"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Like I said, I have no clue about it and just wondered why the compiler can't read this.

Comment: A compiler is just for a high level language like C. You need an assembler.

Comment: This looks like the assembly output from running gcc against a c file.  What command did you use to generate this?

Comment: Compilation consists of many steps. C source code is compiled to object files, which on Linux are usually relocatable ELF files. Similarly, assembly source code is assembled to object files using an assembler such as `as`. Then they are linked to an executable binary using a linker such as `ld`. A compiler like `gcc` usually combines all these steps. So you can actually just call `gcc -o 0x0c 0x0c.s` and get an executable 64-bit ELF binary from this code. The puzzle probably intends that you do learn what most of this means.